# COM library for Explorer-like system views

Tags: c++, windows, shell, controls

To provide a Windows Explorer-like view of the user's system, we have been using the shell controls from LogicNP (formerly Sky Software), but these have deficiencies, e.g., no support for Win7 libraries. The vendor has not responded to our inquiries about updates, so we're looking to replace the package.

Requirements:

- ActiveX (no managed code or MFC)
- Tree and list views of the system
- Per-item checkboxes
- 32- and 64-bit versions

Any recommendations for a replacement product?

TIA.

Comment: Nobody can make money with this.  Use IExplorerBrowser

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point we still have to support XP. IExplorerBrowser requires at least Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you said you need to support Windows XP:
I accomplished this by using the Shell API to enumerate files & folders and then I used custom drawing to draw the correct icons for each shell item in a standard listview control. It was a fair bit of work and I don't know exactly what you need your shell view to accomplish, but this may be the best option.

This might be a good place to start reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776889.aspx